# Arduino hanging when data sent via bluetooth serial

Tags: c++, serialization, bluetooth, arduino

Below is the code being used by Arduino to extract two integers at a time, from formatted text in the serial. The format being two numbers. each followed by a comma, eg  51,7,   After reading in the ints, it is supposed to do stuff with them, then loop back and go again, unless there is no data, then it is supposed to skip past the if and do stuff using the current int values.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

char rx_byte = 0;
String rx_str[2] = {""};
int nums[2] = {0},  a;
int PIN = 13;
boolean not_read = true;

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {    // is a character available? 
    memset(nums, 0, sizeof(nums));
    rx_str[0] = "";
    rx_str[1] = "";  
    a = 0;
    while( a < 2 ){
      not_read = true;
      while(not_read){
         rx_byte = Serial.read();  // get the character
         if ((rx_byte >= '0') && (rx_byte <= '9')) {
            rx_str[a] += rx_byte;
         }  // if ((rx_byte >= '0') && (rx_byte <= '9'))
         else if (rx_byte == ',') {
            not_read = false;
            a++;   
         }  // else if (rx_byte == ',')
      }  // while(not_read) 
    } // while(int a < 2)
    nums[0] = rx_str[0].toInt();
    nums[1] = rx_str[1].toInt();  
  } // if (Serial.available() > 0)
  // do stuff with ints
} // void loop
```

This turnout works fine when the Arduino is plugged into the usb and the right data is entered into the serial monitor. The problem is, when the data is written by another program in c, using bluetooth with an HC-05-1 module, when there is no data, arduino hangs at the if statement waiting for serial input, instead of skipping past and doing  stuff. Below is the C++ code for writing the data.

```
void right( double times[3] ) {
   nums[0] = (int) times[0];
   nums[1] = (int) times[1];
   int  bytes_written  = 0; // bytes_read  = 0;  
   printf( "\n   nums[0]: %d  ", nums[0]);
   printf( "\n   nums[1]: %d  ", nums[1]);
   sprintf( buf, "%d,%d,", nums[0],nums[1] );
   printf( "\n   writing  ");
   puts(buf);
   bytes_written  = write(s, buf, sizeof(buf));
   printf("\n   %d Bytes written to bluetooth", bytes_written);
   printf("\n +----------------------------------+\n\n");  
}
```

And this is sample output from function `right()`

```
   nums[0]: 4  
   nums[1]: 2  
   writing  4,2,

   15 Bytes written to bluetooth
  +----------------------------------+
```

I dont kmow how relevant this is but here some output from function `right()` when the bluetooth and board are not powered up.

```
  nums[0]: 16  
  nums[1]: 5  
   writing  16,5,
16,5,
  15 Bytes written to bluetooth
 +----------------------------------+
```

Not sure where that extra line of output comes from. Last week it used to output `0 Bytes written to bluetooth` without the extra line, but changes have been made since then.

Edit.... 
Patrick Trentin's diagnosis was right.

```
sprintf( buf, "%d,%d,", nums[0],nums[1] );
```

needed to be changed to

```
int str_len = sprintf( buf, "%d,%d,", nums[0],nums[1] );
```

and

```
bytes_written  = write(s, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

needed to be changed to

```
bytes_written  = write(s, buf, str_len);
```

It was a bit disappointing how long the read process took, so some pretty serious optimization is needed, but it does seem to do what was intended... eventually.

Comment: Exactly how do you know that it hangs at `if (Serial.available() > 0)` rather than in some other place? Also, why do you write `15` bytes to bluetooth, when in the first case `4` would be sufficient, and in the second case `5` would be enough?

Comment: I think it hangs at the if because as soon as i enter data it starts doing the stuff that it is supposed to and continues until it catches up and has read all the data then it hangs again until more data is sent.  I can tell by series of led flashes what data is being executed and when all the data is read.

Comment: I'd rather say that it is more likely it hangs at `Serial.read()`. Once you get past `Serial.available()` you are committed to read `2` values, you *ignore* anything else up in the input buffer and don't get past that point up until when you get that data. There's the chance `Serial` contains something else when you use it with *bluetooth*, try to print all characters you read.

Comment: About the 15 bytes, Iam not sure about that, I just did what it does when the code shown is run. But now you mention it perhaps that is excessive for 4 text characters. Im still learning and are not sure how many bytes are supposed to be in an asci  character, but Ill be looking into that.

Comment: One `ASCII` character equals one `byte`.

Comment: The data is entered via arrows in a gtk spin boxes and there is scope to enter data alot faster than it is processed by arduino test program I am using.  As I follow the led flashes I see the data being processed in the same order that it is written, until it is all read then waits for more.  Good point but why does it enter into the if when there is no data in bluetooth and not using serial port.

Comment: You should test it out, I don't have the device with me so I cannot do much more than guessing a reasonable explanation. Though it wouldn't be the first time `Serial` happens to contain some garbage right after boot, at least in my experience.

Comment: Ive got no idea why it uses 15 bytes instead of 4

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will look into how to give it a flush before the first write

Comment: It is likely that `buf` has size `15`, my point is that `sprintf()` returns you the number of `bytes` that it wrote in `buf`, so you should use that value instead of  `sizeof(buf)`. -- **n.b.**, `Serial.flush()` doesn't clear the `input` buffer of `Serial`, if you want to do it then you must do it manually.

Comment: Ill try printing what the arduino reads in serial monitor while comparing what is written in terminal

Comment: I just looked it does have 15 , Ill try reducing it to 4 as well, aand refresh it each time it is used. gee your good

Comment: Don't reduce it, otherwise when you must print values like `123,213,` the buffer won't be large enough. Just use the right length value when you call `write()`.

Comment: Thanks Its hard for me to keep up.  The penny finally dropped about the return from sprintf and swap it for the sizeof, that sounds real promising.

Comment: Thanks again youve given me a number of good ideas. It will take me a while being so slow, but Ill be back to edit my question to say which one worked

Comment: Don't tag C++ questions as C. If you don't even know which programming language you are coding in, how can you hope to ever write a correct program?

Comment: Use SerialEvent interruption instead of checking inside the loop. But if you check inside loop put a delay between checks.